# OptaPlanner: How to display your datasets on the graph

Tags: jfreechart, optaplanner

I'm looking at the code for OptaPlanner, and I am having trouble understanding how I can pass in my own data(that can display on the graph for Project Job Scheduling). I read the documentation which said that there are solver objects and I can pass data into them, however I can't find anything in the documentation regarding how to display the xml example files on the charts.

Is there another way to do this without creating my own XML file?

Answer (score 1):

That display is part of `optaplanner-examples`, so it's an example to inspire you and customize to your needs, it's not an end user application. The UI of that example uses **JFreeChart**, [see that code here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/swingui/ProjectJobSchedulingPanel.java).